# Saving a text box to pdf in R

Tags: r, text, r-grid

I am trying to create a bullet-point type list in R, and want to save it in pdf, which successfully resulted in printing the bullet-point list on a window:

```
 a = paste0("Starting portfolio value: $", prettyNum(1000000,big.mark=",",scientific=F))
 b = "Inflation assumptions of 3% annually"
 c = "Average annual returns: 6%"
 d ="Average annual volatility: 7%"

 text = paste(a, "\n", b, "\n", c, "\n", d, "\n")

 library(grid)
 grid.points(x = rep(10,4), y = c(295, 318, 338, 360), pch = 15, gp = gpar(cex = 0.5))
 grid.text(text, x = 0.05, hjust = 0, gp = gpar(fontsize = 11))
```

[image]

However, I would like to be able to save this to a pdf, along with two other graphs on the same page.

Any way of doing that? Thanks!

Comment: you can use `textplots` from the `gplots` package

Comment: That would be to implement text. How about the bullet points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
a = paste0("Starting portfolio value: $", prettyNum(1000000,big.mark=",",scientific=F))
b = "Inflation assumptions of 3% annually"
c = "Average annual returns: 6%"
d ="Average annual volatility: 7%"

pdf('out.pdf',width=5,height=5)
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,5), bty='n',
     xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab='', ylab='')
text(1,4,a, pos=4)
text(1,3,b, pos=4)
text(1,2,c, pos=4)
text(1,1,d, pos=4)
points(rep(1,4),1:4, pch=15)
dev.off()
```

Here's the approximate output:

[image]

Comment: Can I save this plot along with another plot in the same page of the pdf?

Comment: Yes. You can add the `text` and `points` lines to any other plot, or you could use `layout` to put this next to another plot.

Comment: So here is what I hope to achieve: I have two graphs and this text plot. Imagine if the page was divided in four quadrants, but the top two quadrants are merged. I would want to have the first graph in the top half of the page, and the text box and the second graph in the bottom two quadrants.. Do you think that would be feasible with layout?

Comment: Do `layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))`, then call your three plots in sequence thereafter.

Comment: +1 for all these great ideas!! I can't thank you enough! It does exactly what I need!